# SOAP UI 5.7.0: Error The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

Tags: web-services, soapui

In SOAP latest version 5.7.0, trying to check SOAP request for java based application. But, getting below error. Tried multiple options provided over stack overflow to update "set JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dsoapui.https.protocols="TLSv1.2" in soapui batch file and "-Dsoapui.https.protocols=TLSv1.2" in SoapUI-5.7.0.vmoptions file. Also, try to update same at java level as well. Still same issue is occuring.

- ERROR:Exception in request: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: The server selected protocol version TLS10 is not accepted by client preferences [TLS12]

FYI, this was working in previous version of SOAP but after upgrade same thing is not working as expected.

It will be helpful that solution is provided for same.

Solution on TLS related error in latest SOAP UI 5.7.0

Comment: Can you please try with `TLSv1.0` instead?

Answer (score 1):

Try with following:

Open `"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.7.0\bin\SoapUI-5.7.0.vmoptions"`

Append `-Dweblogic.security.SSL.minimumProtocolVersion=TLSv1.0` if it's not there already.

Then Open `"C:\Program Files\SmartBear\SoapUI-5.7.0\jre\conf\security\java.security"`

Find `jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms`, either comment it with # or remove specific versions, e.g. `TLSv1, TLSv1.1`

Restart SoapUI and try again.